# knockoutjs, How do you use an observableArray to store the history of another observable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I'm new to Knockoutjs. I have a very simple model with name, value and history variables. I've tried several approaches but can not get the history to update more then 1 iteration. Most approaches failed with scope access issues. As I said I'm new to knockeout. I've also included this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K3gJT/54/) that illustrates the issues well.

```
this.tlmname = ko.observable();
this.tlmval = ko.observable();
this.history = ko.observableArray();


var telemItem = function (data) {

     this.tlmname = ko.observable();
     this.tlmval = ko.observable();
     this.history = ko.observableArray();
     this.update(data);

 };

ko.utils.extend(telemItem.prototype, {

     update: function(data) {


         this.tlmname(data.tlmname|| "Cheese");
         this.tlmval(data.tlmval || 0);
         this.history.push(data.tlmval);

         if (this.history().length > 50) this.history.shift();

     }

 });

var telemetryViewModel = function(telemVars) {

    this.telemVars = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(telemVars, function(data) {
            return new telemItem(data);
        }));

function UpdateModel( modelView ) {

    $.getJSON('/gtr/tests/ko/requestTelemetry.php', 
    function(data)
    {
        //modelView.telemVars(data.telemVars);
        //modelView(data.telemVars);

        modelView.update(data.telemVars);
        modelView.telemVarsDirect( getDirectVM( data.telemVars ) );

    }               
)};
```

Comment: I don't understand, your fiddle appears to work perfectly, in that I update the price of each item, and it is added to the history. What is the problem?

Comment: you have some syntax errors in your code as well like an extra semicolon at the end and im not sure where function UpdateModel lives looks like you want it to be part of telemetryViewModel but not sure. JSlint it. But your fiddle does work.